# Get Namespace of Component in Core Service

Tags: core-service

I get a ComponentData object and need to query the Component's content using XPath.  I am using the full XPath to the field.

Currently I'm getting it from the Schema, but wonder if it's possible to get the Namespace directly from the Component?

```
SchemaData schema = client.Read(compData.Schema.IdRef, new ReadOptions()) as SchemaData;
string namespaceUri = schema.NamespaceUri;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
ComponentData component = (ComponentData)channel.Read("[ComponentId]", new ReadOptions());
XElement xComponent = XElement.Parse(component.Content);
string ns = xComponent.FirstAttribute.Value;
```